# How can i avoid Typecasting in c# in my following code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, interface

I have Base class Room

---

```
public class Room
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int minX;
    public int minY;

    public Room(int width, int height, int minX, int minY)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.minX = minX;
        this.minY = minY;
    }

    public virtual void GenerateRoom()
    {
    }
 }
```

---

There are two types of room `ProcedualRoom` and `PredefinedRoom`

---

```
public class ProcedualRoom: Room
{
   public ProcedualRoomData data;
}
```

---

```
 public class PredefinedRoom: Room
{
   public PredefinedRoomData data;
}
```

---

Both classes have their respective data which are different from each other `ProcedualRoomData` and `PredefinedRoomData`

---

---

In some other class where I am loading all the rooms

```
ILoad[] objsToLoad = GetComponentsInChildren<ILoad>();
    foreach (Room r in procedualDungeon.rooms)
    {
        foreach (ILoad obj in objsToLoad)
        {
            obj.Load(r);
        }
    }
```

---

When I load Room I have to do typecast like this

---

```
 public void Load(Room room)
 {

    if (room is PredefinedRoom)
    {
        Load((room as PredefinedRoom).data);
    }
    else
    {
        ProcedualRoom pRoom = (room as ProcedualRoom);
        Load(pRoom);
    }
}
```

---

Is there any other method to avoid typecasting  ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a virtual method on `Room` named `Load` and having each overload do what needs to be done to call Load?

Comment: Oh, reading over your code, you have a Load method on Room. Just make it virtual and have to overload do what they need. Generally, whenever you see a base class method looking at the types of its subclasses, there's a possible solution with a virtual method

Comment: I thought of same but then I have to pass  `ILoad[] objsToLoad` as an argument

Comment: @Flydog57 Load method is not inside Room, It is inside some other class where if I pass room it takes the appropriate data from `ProcedualRoom` and loads the necessary thing

Comment: Ok, create the virtual methods in Room and its subclasses. Then have the overloads call the Load method appropriately

Comment: so I did this  `public override void Load(ILoad[] objsToLoad)
    {

    }`, But now I have to pass `ILoad[] objsToLoad` is it good practice?

Comment: Sure, but I'd pass it as `IEnumerable<ILoad>` rather than as an array. The method simply iterated over the collection, so IEnumerable makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class RoomData and add a filed with this type in Room class. ProcedualRoomData and PredefinedRoomData will derive from RoomData

```
public class RoomData 
{
...
}  

public class  ProcedualRoomData: RoomData {
...
} 

public class  PredefinedRoomData: RoomData {
...
}

public class Room
{
    public RoomData data;
....
}
```